# El shaddai word meaning

Tags: bible, god

Recently I read old testment.

But here If El Shaddai meaning is god of Mountain, then no Almighty God words inside Old testment?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 commonly known interpretations of the meaning of [El Shaddai:](https://www.biblestudytools.com/bible-study/topical-studies/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-name-shaddai.html#google_vignette)

> Among Christians, the most common interpretation of shaddai today is
> “mighty,” and El Shaddai would translate to **“God Almighty.”** Coinciding
> with this, one suggested root meaning for El Shaddai is “The
> Overpowerer,” meaning God will do what He purposes to do, overpowering
> all opposition.
>
> Some interpret shaddai as “sufficient,” and God is the **“All-sufficient
> One.”** Either interpretation—mighty or sufficient—works for me, because
> the Almighty is the God who is enough! He is more than sufficient to
> meet any need. He is power and provision. In great compassion, He
> sustains, nourishes and protects me. He takes my weakness and gives me
> strength. He takes my inadequate resources and in His sufficiency uses
> them for His great and powerful purposes.
>
> Yet another possible meaning of El Shaddai is **“The God of the
> Mountain.”** Some Messianic teachers say shaddai comes from the Akkadian
> word shaddu, meaning “mountain.” God lives in heaven, but He also
> inhabited a mountain top—Mount Sinai. It was on this mountain Moses
> met with God and received the Ten Commandments.

All interpretations work for me because they are true about God. He is almighty. He is all-sufficient. He is the God of the mountain and every mountain for that matter. While "El Shaddai" is not the only term used to describe God's power and might in the Old Testament, it is one of several titles that convey a different aspect of His nature. Other terms include "Yahweh Sabaoth" (Lord of Hosts), "El Elyon" (Most High God), and "Adonai" (Lord).

**El Gibbor:** This title translates to "Mighty God" or "Heroic God" and speaks to God's strength and power (Isaiah 9:6).

**El Olam:** Meaning "Everlasting God" or "God of Eternity," this name speaks to God's eternal nature and enduring power (Genesis 21:33).

**El Roi:** "God Who Sees" is a name given by Hagar after encountering God in the wilderness, signifying God's omniscience and attentive care (Genesis 16:13).

**Yahweh Nissi:** "The Lord Is My Banner" declares God's victory and leadership over His people, symbolized by a banner or flag (Exodus 17:15).

**Yahweh Jireh:** "The Lord Will Provide" reflects God's provision and faithfulness, as demonstrated in the story of Abraham and Isaac (Genesis 22:14).

**Yahweh Shalom:** "The Lord Is Peace" signifies God's role in bringing peace and wholeness to His people (Judges 6:24).

**Yahweh Tsidkenu:** "The Lord Our Righteousness" emphasizes God's role as the source of righteousness and justice (Jeremiah 23:6).